# I can't remove the pressed effect of buttons in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to remove the pressed effect from button on IE9. In all other browsers I have no problems.

Please take a look to the code

HTML

```
<button class="fancy">howdy!</button>
```

CSS

```
.fancy {
    width: 60px;
    height: 30px;    
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    display: block;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 11px;
    background: green;
    outline: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 11px;
}

.fancy:active,.fancy:focus
{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border: none;
    outline:none;
    text-indent: 0;
    line-height: 11px;
}
```

Working demo http://jsfiddle.net/MDfvE/

As you can see, when you click the button on IE9 you will see that the text is moved to the right and bottom. I want to remove that.

Any clue? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe try setting a style for :visited and :links?

Comment: It's a button element, not an anchor.

Comment: A duplicate question has the only correct answer I’ve found: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21163265/2816199 .

Answer (score 1):

IE only recognizes the :active pseudo class when the element is an anchor.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848864%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Try changing the button element to an anchor tag and adjust the styling to recreate the look you had for your button.

Comment: Yes, that is a good solution, but the webapp where I'm working on uses focusable elements (the users selects the proper button using the TAB key) by using the :focus pseudoclass. I tried to change but that brings to us other problems, so I prefer to have a little visual issue with IE9 than fixing IE7/IE8. So use buttons it's a great solution, and only IE9 has this problem. The weird thing is that doesn't seem to be a css value what displace the text.

Comment: By the way, checking the link that you've provided, in the bottom of the page says

"Applies to: 
A, ABBR, ACRONYM, ADDRESS, B, BIG, BLOCKQUOTE, BODY, CAPTION, CENTER, CITE, CODE, COL, COLGROUP, DD, DFN, DIR, DIV, DL, DT, EM, FORM, hn, HTML, I, IMG, INPUT, INPUT type=button, INPUT type=checkbox, INPUT type=file, INPUT type=image, INPUT type=password, INPUT type=radio, INPUT type=reset, INPUT type=submit, INPUT type=text, ..."

And if you try the code that I posted in jsfiddle, you can change the background color of the button and IE applies that change, so It's recognizing that selector.

Answer (score 1):

It's a browser behaviour, a simple solution is to use a link tag instead of button (if its triggering a javascript function).

```
<a href="#" onclick="myfunction()" role="button"><img src="myimg"/></a>
```

If you still want to use the `<button>`, I've found that there are some characteristics on each browser (in a simple debug):

- **Chrome** adds `outline` and `padding`
- **Firefox** adds a whole lot of stuff with the standart button border
- **IE** messes with the inner text `position`

So to fix them, you have to manipulate the pseudo selectors for the button behaviour. And for IE, a good solution is to envolve your text on a  element, and make it relative positioned. Like so:

```
<button type="button" class="button"><span>Buttom or Image</span></button>

<style>
    button,
    button:focus,
    button:active{
        border:1px solid black;
        background:none;
        outline:none;
        padding:0;
    }
    button span{
        position: relative;
    }
</style>
```

[Pen](http://codepen.io/teefars/pen/avNRMZ?editors=110)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Anyway, this questions was 3 years ago, I don't even work in that project anymore. As I said in the previous question, the app had some usability, so changing a button to a link element has some implications for that matter.