# Remove 3D press effect Internet Explorer button

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to remove the *3D click effect* on buttons in Internet Explorer (I'm using IE10).

I have tried with:

```
button:active {
  position: relative; 
  left: -1px; 
  top: -1px; 
}
```

But this makes the entire button shifts 1 px top-left (not the behavior I'm looking for).
I want just to make the text stay in the same position even when clicked.

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704736/i-cant-remove-the-pressed-effect-of-buttons-in-internet-explorer-9) with no good answers so I'm asking here.

This is my code so far:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aliFb

Comment: In other browsers this does the trick:

    <input type="button" value="My Button" style="border: 1px solid"/>

But I just tested and this doesn't work on IE.

But how about using an <a href..> with display block?

Comment: Just for a semantic correctness

Comment: Looking at bootstrap I see the same effect on IE. I think you are deep in system land here (like for radios, selects, ...)

Comment: Can't belive there's not a solution :(

Comment: If you want to use a background image here's a quite ugly solution (if you haven't already found it yourself)
http://www.pmob.co.uk/temp/input-rollover-test.htm
Seems as if the effect is only applied to the value text.

Comment: Oh no please, high dpi & bandwidth killer solution :( thanks however

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Had the same problem right now... It's a bit late, so I don't know whether the answer would still be applicable.

My solution was to put the button's text within a `span` element then set the `style` to `transform: translateY(1px);`. And no more unnecessary press effect. I was a bit apprehensive before trying it, as it would mess with FF, Chrome, and Safari for Windows. But weirdly, they seem to ignore it (for now at least). Tested on 28, 27, and 5.1 respectively. Also, I'm using IE 10.

Good luck

Comment: Actually, `transform: translate(0, 0)` does the trick perfectly! Still a hack, but works glitchless.

Comment: IE9 should be dead by now.

Answer (score 0):

I try this , it works perfectly .

```
button: active span,
button: focus span{position: relative;top: 0px;left: 0px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

`transform: translate(0, 0);` works for IE11. Thanks @tomekwi.

My button text that was jumping was inside a ::before pseudo element, so I used the following to solve the issue:

```
.myButton:active::before {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

But in the end maybe it's better to just let it jump in IE.

[image]